# AppData\Local\Microsoft folders for sharepoint users

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I found below path in a SharePoint 2010 web front end servers
what is this useful if I delete this folder any impact on SharePoint farm or SharePoint web applications?

```
C:\Users\spadmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft
```

**Folders:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting Microsoft folder does not effect on SharePoint farm and web application. directly ,but It's not recommended to delete this folder because it will remove and may be crush all user profile Microsoft program settings.

> Note : these settings is not related to SharePoint settings like SharePoint permission.

If you need to delete this folder because it has a big size , so you should leave the main folders then delete its unwanted files not the main folder.

Also, you should check The sample of user settings that stored at Microsoft Folder like

- Program settings like Visual Studio and TFS ...etc.
- IE temporary files are stored under temporary internet files under Windows folder.
- History of Windows Activities.

Comment: i have some users before i was used for sharepoint installation and administration ,now i am not using these users and these users folders has big size on c:/ drive , can i delete these folders?

Comment: it's associated with a risk but I think if this users is not service account and they will not login again to this server you can do it